# How do I view a property in H2 SQL

Tags: sql, h2

How does one view a property with a SELECT query? I've got some properties that I need to see the value of in a running H2 DB. I've got the Console app up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was as easy as I thought. Say the property is "SIZE", then

```
SELECT @SIZE
```

D'oh